# Collections.Counter in Python3

Tags: python, optimization, python-3.x, collections

Can you suggest how I might make the following code more efficient:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1,1,3,3,1,3,2,1,4,1,6,6]

c = Counter(a)

length = len(set(c.values()))

normalisedValueCount = {}
previousCount = 0
i = 0
for key in sorted(c, reverse=True):
    count = c[key]

    if not previousCount == count:
        i = i+1
        previousCount = count

    normalisedValueCount[key] = i/length

print(normalisedValueCount)
```

It basically gives a dictionary similar to counter, but instead of counting the number of occurrences, it contains a weighting based on the number of occurrences.

- The number 1 is associated with 1.0 (`4/length`) because it occurs the most often.
- 2 and 4 occur the least often and are associated with the value `1/length`.
- 6 is the second least occurring value and is associated with `2/length`.
- 3 is the third least occurring value and is associated with `3/length`.

Some more examples:

- The list `a[1,2,3]` results in a `normalisedValueCount` of 1:1.0, 2:1.0, 3:1.0.
- The list `a[2,1,2]` results in a `normalisedValueCount` of 2:1.0, 1:0.5.
- The list `a[2,1,2,3]` results in a `normalisedValueCount` of 2:1.0, 1:0.5, 3:0.5.
- The list `a[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,3,3]` results in a `normalisedValueCount` of 2:1.0, 3:0.66666, 1:0.33333.

Comment: Your most recent edit changed the contents of the last list but didn't update the `normaizedValueCount`s.  Are those the results you would be expecting?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you code is doing, it doesn't look like any normalization I've seen. I'd offer a more specific suggestion on restructuring if I understood what you are doing.

You:

1. Put a in a counter
2. Put that counter's values into a set
3. sort the keys of the counter

I'd look for another approach that doesn't involve so much moving around.

```
if not previousCount == count:
```

better as

```
if previousCount != count:
```

**EDIT**

1. Counter.most_common returns what you are fetching using sorted(c, reverse=True)
2. itertools.groupby allows you group together common elements nicely (such as the same count)
3. enumerate can be used to count over the elements in a list rather then keeping track of the counter

My code:

```
c = Counter(a)
length = len(set(c.values()))
counter_groups = itertools.groupby(c.most_common(), key = lambda x: x[1]))
normalisedValueCount = {}
for i, (group_key, items) in enumerate(counter_groups)
    for key, count in items:
        normalisedValueCount[key] = (i+1)/length
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be?- counter_groups = itertools.groupby(reversed(combinationsCount.most_common()), key = lambda x: x[1])

Comment: @Baz, I may be wrong, but I don't think so. `most_common` returns the elements from the most common to the least common. Of course your the best judge of whether that is what you wanted.

Comment: Yes, but if the items are sorted from most to least common then the __for loop__ section will start with the most common number when i = 0. This will result in the most common values being associated with the smaller __normalisedValueCounts__ ((i+1)/length), which is the opposite of what we want. Thanks again!

Comment: @Baz, okay, I guess I misread the original code. Your welcome.